# How to get the file and upload it using Node.js and Postman

Tags: node.js, postman, multer

I need one help. I am sending file using Postman and I need to upload it inside required folder using Node.js. I am explaining my code below.

> server.js:

```
var express=require('express');
var morgan = require('morgan');
var http=require('http');
var bodyParser= require('body-parser');
var methodOverride = require('method-override');
var mongo = require('mongojs');
var session = require('express-session');
var app=module.exports=express();
var server=http.Server(app);
var port=8889;
var api=require('./api/api.js');
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));     // set the static files location /public/img will be /img for users
app.use(morgan('dev'));                     // log every request to the console
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false,limit: '5mb' }))    // parse application/x-www-form-urlencoded
app.use(bodyParser.json({limit: '5mb'}))    // parse application/json
app.use(methodOverride());    
app.post('/upload',api.upload);    
server.listen(port);
console.log("Server is running on the port"+port);
```

> api.js:

```
var multer  = require('multer');
var storage =multer.diskStorage({
  destination: function (req, file, callback) {
    callback(null, './../uploads');
  },
  filename: function (req, file, callback) {
    callback(null, Date.now()+'-'+file.originalname);
  }
});
var upload = multer({ storage: storage});
exports.upload=function(req,res){
}
```

Actually I am posting the file using `postman` whose screen shot is given below.

[image]

Here my requirement is the file will upload into the required folder `i.e-uploads` and the uploaded file name will return as response to user. Please help me.

Comment: have you added `app.listen(port)` in your last line of  `server.js`?

Comment: yes let me to edit that

Comment: @Mr.D : I have updated my post. Do you have any solutions ?

Comment: try to place `var server = http.Server(app)` after your `app` declarations just before `server.listen(port)`.

Comment: That is there already. Please check this and this is not my issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You haven't actually used the multer here. You have created upload using multer but you did not use it.

Try the following code:

```
app.post('/upload', upload.single('file'), function (req, res, next) { 
     // req.file is the `file` file
     // req.body will hold the text fields, if there were any
})
```

where upload will be the var upload = multer({ storage: storage}); variable.

Comment: How to return the uploaded file name as response ?

Comment: All the details of the upload file will be available in req.file.

Comment: I did like this `app.post('/upload',upload.single('file'), function (req, res, next) { 
   var data={'filename':res.req.file.filename};
   res.send(data);
})` but it does not send any response.

Comment: You have a typo here. `var data={'filename':res.req.file.filename};` where it should be `var data={'filename': req.file.filename};`. And also make sure to make use of return while sending data. like : `return res.send(data);`.